# Is there a way to do relative (percentage or rem) line-height in styled-components?

Tags: react-native, styled-components

Styled components claim to cover all of css but I've run into this simple but significant issue. I need to enlarge my line-height but in a relative way, otherwise the line gets cut (it's height is smalled than the letters).

When I try to use rem or % as unit, I get an error saying a number type is expected instead of a string.

Comment: can you add your styles here

Comment: Here is a Snack with demo code. (only works on ios device though, no idea why)
https://snack.expo.io/@eskel/styled-components-line-height

Answer (score 0):

**line-height:** 100% means 100% of the font size for that element, not 100% of its height. In fact, the line height is always relative to the font size, not the height, unless its value uses a unit of absolute length (px, pt, etc). another option which you can try is using **table-cell**

```
#wrapper{
  height: 40px;
  width:200px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to work that way. When I enter line-height: 100, I get 100px tall lines. Also percentage sign is ignored, give it a try.
https://snack.expo.io/@eskel/styled-components-line-height-100

Comment: you are trying to use line-height make it vertical-align right ? if that's your decided thing you can achieve it by `flex`. can you tell me for what you are using line-height if you can tell that i can help you.